# Turn off Pop-up blocker if Internet explorer automatically

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript

Is there any way to turn off pop-up blocker of Internet explorer automatically from using javascript or vbscript? I don't want to use an activeX object as it is a security threat for my application hence i can't use GetObject.

Please suggest.

Comment: Think about it. If there were, the people who's popups you want to block would turn it off !

Comment: The only reasonable thing you can do is to inform the visitors about the pop-up, like Adobe flash player download page. Or you can read, and make a modal window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mplungjan points out, obviously you can't do this.

Instead, work *with* the pop-up blocker. Only try to open new windows in *direct* response to a user action, such as a click. Pop-up blockers are smart enough to allow you to do that.

Better yet, don't use pop-ups at all. There's very, very little call for them in modern web programming. Instead, position elements above other elements in the z-order. Those few use-cases where an actual separate window is appropriate can be handled in direct response to user events.